# How make select2-container top 0?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

How can I adjust the position of Select2 container so that the search box is position right over the original select.

[So that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BphqC.jpg)

```js
var select = $('.select');

select.select2({
  width: "100%",
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  dropdownParent: $('.selectWrap'),
}).on('select2:open', function() {
  var container = $('.select2-container:last-child').find('.select2-dropdown--below');

  container.css({
    top: -27 + 'px',
    background: '#000'
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectWrap">
  <select class="select" name="" id="">
    <option value="1" selected>Choose 1</option>
    <option value="2">Choose 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556402/select2-change-container-position), but it not works for me. What my mistake?

Comment: For starters, wrong attempt at selecting the element. The class `select2-dropdown--below` gets dynamically added to the element with the class `select2-container`, but with `.find()` you are looking for _descendants_ inside of that element.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add default style of selectWrap class first.

```
.selectWrap {
 position: relative,
 top: 0px, // top position you wanna set
 right: 100px, // right position you wanna set
}
```

Then add parentClass wrap your select box:

```
<div class="selectWrap" style="<code here>">
   <select name="search" type="text" class="form-control select2"></select>
</div>
```